# python urlopen : only the first attribute of the URL is taken via data

Tags: python, post, urlencode, urlopen

I'm trying to scrap a website.
It consists in a soccer website that lists all the matches of all the seasons.
So i'm trying to scrap the html pages of every game of every season
Here is the url : http://www.lfp.fr/ligue1/calendrier_resultat#sai=77&jour=1

What I am doing is :

```
url = 'http://www.lfp.fr/ligue1/calendrier_resultat#'
data = {'sai':77,'jour':10}
url_values = urlencode(data)
response = urlopen(url,url_values)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
```

sai is the season
and jour is the week

the problem is that the page given only depends on the 'sai' value, no matter what 'jour' is equal to, it will always returns the same page and it will always be the last week.

For example I can enter an url like this :
http://www.lfp.fr/ligue1/calendrier_resultat#sai=77OUHIGYGO8TY98
It will never care what comes after sai=77.
I don't know why it does this and I really need some help.
Thanks

Comment: The server is probably ignoring anything after the `#`, so I'd be surprised if either of those two parameters is making a difference in the URL. But also I think you're `POST`ing that data as a form to `url`, not simply getting that URL. Anyway, it looks like the content is being loaded dynamically using javascript so you should use selenium. Bonne chance!

Comment: Oh I have been hearing about selenium. I guess I am going to consider this as well. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some other stackoverflow posts' answers,I finally resolved the problem.

The problem here was that the URL part after # is a client-side part that is never sent to the server. Actually, there is a true URL that is sent to the server and I found it using Mozilla : you just go to the developer tools and go to the network tab. Scroll through the tab elements on the left side and for each element you will see the corresponding "request URL".
If you pay attention you will find the right element whose request URL looks like to the URL with the # symbol. Just copy-paste it and your problem is resolved.